# Excluding result based on length of a field

Tags: c#, sql, linq

Below is my LINQ query:

```
 list = (from i in context.Cars
    .Where(c => terms.All(t => c.Code.Contains(t) || c.ShortDescription.Contains(t) 
    && c.Code.Replace(" " , "").Length >3))
    select new Model.Cars
    {
        CarId = i.CarId,
        ShortDescription = i.ShortDescription,
        Code = i.Code
    }).Take(250).ToList();\
```

One of the business requirement is to exclude any record where code length is shorter than 3. A lot of these codes have whitespaces in them which is why I put in clause of replacing " " with "". This does not seem to work in my query. I am still getting results where code length is 3. I should only get results where code length is greater than3. It almost seems like the replace is not replacing whitespaces with no space. Everything else works. What am I doing wrong ?

Comment: [Please don't put tags in question titles](https://stackoverflow.com/help/tagging)

Comment: To remove whitespaces use trim() method which will  remove tabs, returns , and spaces.

Comment: @jdweng: only leading/trailing whitespace. Not spaces in between characters.

Comment: Trim only removes spaces a beginning and end.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Operator precedence strikes again.

```
.Where(c => 
    terms.All(t => 
        ( c.Code.Contains(t) || c.ShortDescription.Contains(t) )
        && c.Code.Replace(" " , "").Length > 3
    )
)

if (true || true && false)
    MessageBox.Show("Gotcha!");
```

Comment: OH WOW. I cant believe I missed that!! Thats a lot Ed. I feel silly now lol

Answer (score 0):

Why are you switching bewteen LINQ & lambda syntax?  Had you stuck to the LINQ syntax, you probably would have spotted the precedence problem:

```
list = (from i in context.Cars
    let code = i.Code.Trim()
    where terms.All(t => code.Contains(t) || i.ShortDescription.Contains(t))
          && code.Length > 3

    select new Model.Cars
    {
        CarId = i.CarId,
        ShortDescription = i.ShortDescription,
        Code = code
    }).Take(250).ToList();
```